# How to get client ip address and domain url in configure_services method -core 2.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get the client IP address and current domain from url in configureservices method in startup.cs. Is it possible to retrieve those values ?

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
}

Comment: `ConfigureServices()` is done at startup time , which means it happens before any request received . Are you trying to configure something to get client IP when there's a incoming request ?

Comment: Agree with itminus and I've no idea what "current domain" is meant to mean in this context.

Comment: @itminus yes, I confugured JWT token in configureservices method and my custom logic needs to send email if anything went wrong with the token. So that along with the email, i would like to pass the website IP and requested url.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Its the current url, but i understood its not possible as this executes before httprequest but i just want to check is there any way to get the website ip so that I can send the information along with he email.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){}
```

This method executes before the HTTP request. So, you can not get any HTTP request related information here.